# How to connect Dialogflow integrations to specific environment

Tags: dialogflow-es, integration

I have a Dialogflow chatbot integrated with Facebook Messenger and I created a production environment called "production".

How do I set the Facebook Messenger integration to interact with the production environment? I tried editing the callback URL in the `developers.facebook.com` page but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what to do. The steps I had to take will probably change in the future, as for now it has to do with "beta features", that in the future will no longer be beta for sure.

First, I went to the chatbot definitions (top-left gear icon) and under the "General" tab, I "enabled beta features and APIs".

Then I headed over to the Integrations tab, disabled the Facebook Messenger integration. After that, I turned it on and, before hitting "Start" again, I changed the environment used.

Comment: do you think it is possible to add two different messenger integrations to two environments? the idea is to test dev environment on a separate bot and leave prod one untouched

Comment: @tmac_balla I have no idea. I only tested my dev bot through the console... But maybe it is possible, if you associate them with different webhooks and different Facebook pages